# How to use querystring in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to figure out how to use a querystring with a page I created. Currently my page has a navigation menu that updates the div contents dynamically when you click a link. The navigation menu consists of a bunch of product categories (tomatoes, olive oils, etc).

My problem is that since these are not actual HTML pages, how can I set up a querystring to be able to link to a certain category from a completely different page.

Example:

- Landing: products.html
- Click 1: products.html?tomatoes
- Click 2: products.html?oliveoil

Comment: I think you could achieve that with `window.location.href` + correct regex ([see here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values-in-javascript))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `window.location.hash`, and instead of using a `?` you should use a `#` to split the querystring from the filename. So if you have `products.html#oliveoil` then `window.location.hash` will be `#oliveoil`. You will also be able to set the hash with `window.location.hash = 'What-you-want'`.

Comment: do i have to add the window.location.hash to the onclick event? or do I have to assign every category a unique hash prior to onclick and then link to the full url with hash from a different page? thanks

Comment: From another page you gonna have a link: `products.html#oliveoil`. And on the products.html you got to get the `window.location.hash` after the page was loaded and then you have to tell what content to show. And if you click a menu link the onclick event should change the hash. So it would be good to have some reference with the same name in a data attribute in your menu link.

Comment: You could use anchor tags in addition to the onclick handler to set the hash. `<a id="olive-oil" href="#oliveoil">Olive Oil</a>`

Comment: thank you both for these great answers I got it to work =)